# CSS) hover on animation

Tags: html, css

In a moving box,
I want to make an animation that turns upside down when I raise the mouse.
I want to implement the movement of the box with the keyframe and designate hover, but it doesn't work.

What should I do?

```css
#www{
    background-color: black;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    animation: www 5s infinite;
    transition: 1s;
}
#www:hover{
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
@keyframes www{
    0% {
        transform: translateX(0vw);
    }
    50% {
        transform: translateX(50vw);
    }
    100% {transform: translateX(0vw);}
}
```

```html
<div class="box" id="www">WWW</div>
```

Comment: your keyframe is overriding the hover value

Comment: ..and you don't want an animation anyway. A simple transition is all you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a container to have both `transformation` properties as you can't achieve different `transform` on same element using different `triggers`(`hover` `automatic`)

> Below styles used are for illustration only (to easily understand) you can use according to need and have a `transparent` `background` if want

```js
function func() {
  document.getElementById("www").style.transform = "rotate(180deg)"
}
```

```css
#www {
  background-color: black;
  transition: 1s transform;
  animation: www 10s infinite;
  width: fit-content;
}

@keyframes www {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0vw);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateX(50vw);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0vw);
  }
}

.box1 {
  transition: 1s;
  background-color: red;
  margin-top: 100px;
  width: fit-content;
}

.box1:hover {
  transform: rotate(180deg)
}
```

```html
<div class="box" id="www" onclick="func()">
  <div class="box1">WWW</div>
</div>
```